# instant.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.HOURS) returns value that is greater than original for

Tags: java, java-time

According to the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#truncatedTo-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-) of `Instant.truncatedTo` what it does is

> Truncating the instant returns a copy of the original with fields
>   smaller than the specified unit set to zero.

Thus I expect the hour to be unmodified if I call it with `ChronoUnit.HOURS`. Which also is what I see when I call it with dates after 1970. However, before that it's actually returning a value greater than the original. Is this the intended behavior or am I missing something?

```
    Instant.ofEpochMilli(-1);                                          //1969-12-31T23:59:59.999Z
    Instant.ofEpochMilli(-1).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.HOURS);            //1970-01-01T00:00:00Z
    Instant.ofEpochMilli(1);                                           //1970-01-01T00:00:00.001Z
    Instant.ofEpochMilli(1).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.HOURS);             //1970-01-01T00:00:00Z
    Instant.ofEpochMilli(2*60*60*1000).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.HOURS);  //1970-01-01T02:00:00Z
    Instant.ofEpochMilli(2*60*60*1000-1);                              //1970-01-01T01:59:59.999Z
    Instant.ofEpochMilli(2*60*60*1000-1).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.HOURS);//1970-01-01T01:00:00Z
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this the intended behavior

No it's [a bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8134928) that is fixed in Java 9.

Comment: It has also been [backported to Java SE 8](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8142757)